# OpenLayers set/modify property "projection"

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to set/modify property `projection` of `ol.source.Source`?

No method is allowed like `setProjection`.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

What would be the benefit of changing the projection? Your data source provides data in one projection, right? Using a different projection means that you have a different data source, so you should create new ol.Source instance.

Comment: It's only to have information about the effective projection when i will use :

"getProjection" for this source.

Then, do you suggest to delete current source and create an other?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Projection is set on instantiation, so that it matches the Source's data. Changing it would be inconsistent.